# Trouble Displaying Listings Package

Tags: listings

I will show the settings of the `listings package`, like this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
   backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
   breakatwhitespace=false,
   breaklines=true,
   captionpos=b,
   commentstyle=\color{green},
   deletekeywords={...},
   escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
   frame=leftline,
   keepspaces=true,
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
   morekeywords={documentclass,document,book,article,usepackage,begin,end,newcommand,renewcommand,table,tabular,figure,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
   numbers=left,
   numbersep=5pt,
   numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
   rulecolor=\color{blue},
   showlines=true,
   showspaces=false,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showtabs=false,
   stepnumber=1,
   stringstyle=\color{blue},
   tabsize=2,
   title=\lstname
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listings Package Setting]
\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    deletekeywords={...},
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    frame=leftline,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
    morekeywords={documentclass,document,book,article,usepackage,begin,end,newcommand,renewcommand,table,tabular,figure,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
    rulecolor=\color{blue},
    showlines=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    stringstyle=\color{blue},
    tabsize=2,
    title=\lstname
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

but does not show what I want

[image: listing trouble]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're duplicating your settings as part of a listing to which all the settings apply. As such, not only do you define the listing to `escape` `inside` some set of elements, but you also supply those elements.

I would just temporarily disable the `escapeinside` key-value for the listing that contains your settings:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listings Package Setting, escapeinside={}{}]
```

This provides the output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's because of `escapeinside` it will create area to you that's not in the listing area, you can write `LaTeX` code there for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
   backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
   breakatwhitespace=false,
   breaklines=true,
   captionpos=b,
   commentstyle=\color{green},
   deletekeywords={...},
   escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
   frame=leftline,
   keepspaces=true,
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
   morekeywords={documentclass,document,book,article,usepackage,begin,end,newcommand,renewcommand,table,tabular,figure,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
   numbers=left,
   numbersep=5pt,
   numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
   rulecolor=\color{blue},
   showlines=true,
   showspaces=false,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showtabs=false,
   stepnumber=1,
   stringstyle=\color{blue},
   tabsize=2,
   title=\lstname
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listings Package Setting]
\lstset
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    deletekeywords={...},
    escapeinside={%* book,article are keywords but here!!\\
        I can use \LaTeX codes here like $\Sigma$
     *)},
    frame=leftline,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    language={[LaTeX]{TeX}},
    morekeywords={documentclass,document,book,article,usepackage,begin,end,newcommand,renewcommand,table,tabular,figure,toprule,midrule,bottomrule},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
    rulecolor=\color{blue},
    showlines=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    stepnumber=1,
    stringstyle=\color{blue},
    tabsize=2,
    title=\lstname

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

so the code between escapeinside `%*[Code here]*)` will be LaTeX code and when  you copy past it the `}{` would cause an error because its an error in LaTeX document.

If you want have the exact text use this `escapeinside=%*\{\textbackslash \%\textasteriskcentered\}\{\textasteriskcentered)\}*)`